# write tiny amount of data to block chain? and what block chain are available

Tags: blockchain

I need to write my hash to block chain to make my document legit for life time (want to know how to do that)? Want to know how many block chains are out there and which few are the best ones with least expenses?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a commitment in a Bitcoin transaction in at least a few ways.

1 - including your preimage in `OP_RETURN` data in an zero value output. This can be done by creating your own transaction manually, but you will have to pay the transaction fee. You could also use a service which aggregates many commitments into one final hash, then you share the fee (or don't pay one at all). One example is [OpenTimestamps](https://opentimestamps.org/).

2 - Pedersen commitment - use your preimage to generate an EC public key along with a blinding factor. Does not use extra space in your transaction, therefore can be included in a transaction without additional fees.

3 - Pay-to-contract signature - including another preimage the nonce used in your transaction signature. This also does not take extra space in your transaction, therefore can be included in a transaction without additional fees.

### Resources

- A good resource is waxwing's blog: https://joinmarket.me/blog/blog/finessing-commitments/
- Another good readup on this subject can be found here: https://blog.eternitywall.com/2018/04/13/sign-to-contract/
- James Chiang's Teach Bitcoin curriculum: https://teachbitcoin.io/presentations/ecdsa.html#/
- And wikipedia: [Commitment Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commitment_scheme)

Answer (score 0):

Save your data in any cloud server or ipfs and then deploy any sample smart contract

````
contract MyToken {
    constructor(){}
    string my_doc;
    function set(string memory link) public{
       my_doc=link;
    }

    function get() public view  returns (string memory ){
       return my_doc;
    }
    
}```
//and you can use polygon you can do all the stuff in les then one dollar
//by way you watch a simple tutorial how deploy smart contract using remix ide
````